# Problems on the domain of a simple function

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Let's consider the function
$$f(x) = \log\left(\dfrac{1+x}{x}\right)$$

Considering the properties of the logarithm, I shall always be able to write it as
$$f(x) = \log(1+x) - \log(x)$$
for $x > 0$.

yet the domains of the two functions are different, and the condition $x > 0$ is restrictive. Why so?
Shouldn't the two functions be the same?

Comment: Is your question about the real or the complex logarithm? In the real case, $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$ holds only if all arguments are positive.

Comment: Also, $\log(0)$ is undefined in both Real and Complex Analysis, so you can never have either $x = 0$ or $(x + 1) = 0$, in either type of analysis.  This is regardless of whether you are examining the log of the fraction, or the log of the numerator minus the log of the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The composition of two functions $u : X \to Y$ and $v : Y \to Z$ is the function $v \circ u : X \to Z, (v \circ u)(x) = v(u(x))$. This is a standard definition and it requires that the codomain of $u$ agrees with the domain of $v$. However, if we want we can generalize this definition to *arbitrary* functions $u : X \to Y$ and $v : Y' \to Z$ where $Y \ne Y'$ is allowed. Informally we simply take again $(v \circ u)(x) = v(u(x))$ - but which $x$ are allowed here? Of course we need $u(x) \in Y'$ to apply $v$. Thus we define the domain of $v \circ u$ as the set $u^{-1}(Y')$. This set may very well be empty (e.g. if $Y' \cap Y = \emptyset$) in which case $v \circ u$ is completely uninteresting.

Your function is written as the composition $f = \log \circ g$ with $g(x)  =\dfrac{x+1}{x}$. The domain of $g$ is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and the domain of $\log$ is $(0,\infty)$. We have $g^{-1}((0,\infty)) = (-\infty,-1) \cup (0,\infty)$. Thus the domain of $f$ is $(-\infty,-1) \cup (0,\infty)$.

Your equation $f(x) = \log(x+1) - \log(x)$  is only valid if **both** $x + 1, x$ lie in the domain of $\log$, i.e. if $x \in (0,\infty)$. Thus $f(x)$ and $\log(x+1) - \log(x)$ are *two different functions* because they do not have the same domain.

By the way, expressions like $u \pm v$ with functions $u : X \to \mathbb R$ and $u : X \to \mathbb R$ are usually only defined if $X = X'$. But you can generalize this get the function

$$u \pm v : X \cap X' \to \mathbb R .$$
This happens for $\log(x+1) - \log(x)$.